# vim remove highlight (not search highlight)

Tags: vim

This is a screen of vim editing .bash_profile.  It seem to have used some weird highlighting that I didn't explicitly turn on (e.g. around GaF)

using nohl doesn't help since I didn't initiate a search.  I also tried using 'syntax off', but that just made all the font/text colours white, but the highlights were still in place.

Anyone know what this is, or how to turn it off?

Thanks[image]

Comment: What colorscheme are you using?

Comment: @FDinoff, default colorscheme

Comment: I actually found that the colour is due to the **spell checker** in Vim. This could be disabled by `:set nospell`

Comment: @snowbound this should be an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you see to which *highlight group* this `links to`. Then check your colorscheme for its definition:

```
:highlight <groupname>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I installed SyntaxAttr.vim.  It found the highlight under 'ls' is shDoubleQuote which leads to Constant.  I cleared the highlight on 'Constant', but it just turned the text white.  

SyntaxAttr in action: http://imgur.com/VtFjaip,2wzWDoR#1

After the 'hi clear': http://imgur.com/VtFjaip,2wzWDoR#0

Answer (score 7):

remove all highlighting.

```
hi clear
```

you can find out the group name and

```
hi clear group
```

to disable highlighting on one group

Comment: Worked perfectly for me in a markdown document after wasting far too much time trying to identify the offending syntax group unsuccessfully.

Comment: It's important to note that you shouldn't confuse ***syntax-groups*** with ***highlight groups***. Syntax-groups can be pretty sprawling depending on the language, but each will be linked to a highlight group via `hi def link <syntaxGroup> <highlightGroup>` the highlight groups to which they're linked are common across most languages e.g. Normal, Cursor, Comment, Identifier, etc.

Comment: **TD;DR:** `hi clear <syntaxGroup>` will do nothing whereas `hi clear <highlightGroup>` should work in any context.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had an issue like this every time I opened the `help` window for any command. As the user @snowbound said in the comments, doing `:set nospell` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand on Kent and Ingo Karkat's answers for those that don't wish to install a plugin.

To find out the name of the highlight group in questions, you can use this:

```
" call `:exec SynGroup()` to show the highlight group under the cursor
function! SynGroup()
  let l:s = synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1)
  echo synIDattr(l:s, 'name') . ' -> ' . synIDattr(synIDtrans(l:s), 'name')
endfun
```

(My vimscript is bad, and I copied this from somewhere on the internet long ago. Thank you to that person.)

Anyway, as Kent said, you can use

```
hi clear <group>
```

to disable the highlighting for that group.

For example, `:exec SynGroup()` in vimscript comments gives you

```
vimLineComment -> Comment
```

Then you can use

```
hi clear Comment
```

To remove the highlighting.